# In Chrome DevTools How to prevent script from executing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a page not on my server, where a particular is running during page-loading

```
...other stuff...
<script src="http://someserver.com/script.js"></script>
...other stuff...
```

and causing some problems.
I need to debug this so first I'd like to prevent that script from loading.

How can I do this? All I've found is that I can delete, edit or add a script *after* the page has loaded. But that is not what I need. I need to load the whole page but skip loading this very script.

Comment: Have you tried erasing/commenting the script tag?

Comment: It is *not* on my server, I cannot edit original html

Comment: My bad I misread.  Try this  http://superuser.com/questions/278590/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-specific-js-script-from-a-specific-website

Comment: I'm a bit surprised there is no such option... I'd assume this to be quite a frequent situation

Comment: Hmm I wouldn't think so, this could easily used for evil.. Such as the user finding the validation script reference and disabling it in order to bypass validation and pass unexpected code injection to the server.  Just my thoughts though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google Chrome can now do this for you.

1. Open developer tools
2. Open the network tab
3. Navigate to the site
4. Find the request that loads the script
5. Right-click on the request and select "Block request URL"

Chrome will now block the request that loads that script.  To remove the block:

1. Open the console at the bottom of developer tools, fyi the "Esc" (escape) key will toggle it.
2. Open the "Request Blocking" tab (you'll find it in the 3 dot menu next to the "Console" tab if you don't have the tab available)
3. Click the stop looking icon with the title of "Remove all patterns"

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches to this... the first being the old school way of handling ad blocking (which this is similar to), which is simply create a dns entry in your hosts file (C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on windows) and alias someserver.com to localhost 127.0.0.1:

```
someserver.com  127.0.0.1
```

This, however, has the unfortunate side-effect of not loading ANYTHING from someserver.com.

Another option is to use something like adblock plus, and just add the script to the "Add your own filters" tab, where the syntax for your filter will be:

```
http://someserver.com/script.js
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Are there any other options? This is not the best way because: 1. I need other scripts from that domain. 2. I will eventually need to run this script. Just not during page-loading

Comment: You might be able to use greasemonkey to remove the script tag, but I don't know if you can run greasemonkey scripts before the page loads...